# How do I specify a static array in a Scala 2.8 annotation?

Tags: java, scala, annotations, scala-2.8

I've been building out some annotated domain classes in Scala 2.8.0 using Hibernate Annotations 3.4.0. It's been working fine, except that there are certain annotations which take an array as a parameter. For example, here's a Java annotation that I want to express in Scala:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="passport_id", cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
```

However, the annotation requires an array/set as input:

```
[ERROR] .../Passport.scala:50: error: type mismatch; 
[INFO]  found   : javax.persistence.CascadeType(value PERSIST)
[INFO]  required: Array[javax.persistence.CascadeType]
[INFO]     @OneToMany(mappedBy="passport_id", cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
```

I've tried various parentheses, square/angle/curly brackets, and so on:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="passport_id", cascade=(CascadeType.PERSIST))
@OneToMany(mappedBy="passport_id", cascade=[CascadeType.PERSIST])
@OneToMany(mappedBy="passport_id", cascade=<CascadeType.PERSIST>)
@OneToMany(mappedBy="passport_id", cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST})
```

... but unfortunately I've reached the end of my understanding of Scala/Java annotations. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `cascade=Array(CascadeType.PERSIST)`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'll add a few snippets from the [spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/pdfs/ScalaReference.pdf) to explain why Rex's solution works.

For Scala on the JVM, arguments to annotations that will be retained within the generated class must be constant expressions:

> Instances of an annotation class inheriting from trait
>   scala.ClassfileAnnotation will be stored in the generated class files. ... Additionally, on both Java and .NET, all constructor arguments must be constant expressions.

What are constant expressions?

> **6.24** Constant Expressions Constant expressions are expressions that the
>   Scala compiler can evaluate to a
>   constant. The definition of “constant
>   expression” depends on the platform,
>   but they include at least the
>   expressions of the following forms:
>
> - A literal of a value class, such as an integer
> - A string literal
> - A class constructed with Predef.classOf (§12.4)
> - An element of an enumeration from the underlying platform
> - **A literal array, of the form Array(c1, . . . , cn), where all
>     of the ci ’s are themselves constant
>     expressions**
> - An identifier defined by a constant value definition (§4.1).

You should also be able to refactor the argument to a `final val`. This doesn't seem to work for Arrays, however. I'll raise a bug.

```
class T(value: Any) extends ClassfileAnnotation

object Holder {
   final val as = Array(1, 2, 3)
   final val a = 1
} 

@T(Holder.a)
@T(Holder.as)  // annot.scala:9: error: annotation argument needs to be a constant; found: Holder.as
class Target
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me: @BeanProperty @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=Array(GenerationType.IDENTITY)) var id: Long = _ gives error: found array constant, expected argument of type javax.persistence.GenerationType

Comment: The annotation parameter `strategy` only accepts a single value, as suggested by the compiler error. http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html  `strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY` ought to do the trick.

Answer (score 8):

From Rex Kerr:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="passport_id", cascade=Array(CascadeType.PERSIST))
```

This worked. Thanks.