# Possible to have named constants in scala?

Tags: scala

It looks like annotations require constants in Java. I'd like to do:

```
object ConfigStatics {
  final val componentsToScan = Array("com.example")
}

@PropertySource( ConfigStatics.componentsToScan )   // error: constant value required
class MyConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
}
```

where

```
@PropertySource( Array("com.example") ) 
class MyConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
}
```

is fine.

Sadly, scala doesn't recognize a static final val as a constant value.

Is there's anything to do here, or is it simply not possible to have named constants in scala?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a bug.

SLS 6.24 says a literal array `Array(c1, c2, ...)` is a constant expression.

SLS 4.1 says a constant value definition `final val x = e` means `x` is replaced by `e`.

It doesn't work that way, so either it's a spec bug or an implementation bug.

```
  final val j = Array(1,2,3)
  def k = j  // j
  final val x = 3
  def y = x  // 3
```

This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2449066/1296806) where retronym promised to open a ticket about it.

That was three years ago.  I wonder if there's still a yellow post-it on his terminal?

Comment: Looks like the answer is no.

Answer (score 4):

Your `componentstoScan` is not a constant in the sense that I can change the contained value:

```
object ConfigStatics {
  final val componentsToScan = Array("com.example")
  componentsToScan(0) = "com.sksamuel"
}
```

This will work

```
object ConfigStatics {
  final val componentsToScan = "com.example"
}

@PropertySource(Array(ConfigStatics.componentsToScan))
class MyConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that the compiler's proving that the supplied type is not constant because it has setter methods? Or does it just use knowledge about which of the built-in types are immutable? What determines a constant exactly?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but Som-snytt's answer goes into more details.